# Haskell: Performing an action after a single failure

Tags: haskell

What is the best way to perform a list of  `IO Bool` tests and then perform an action at the end if any one of the `Bool` is a `False`

If I have function that checks to see if a given file exists in a directory

```
check :: FilePath -> IO ()
check s = do 
          r <- doesFileExist s
          putStrLn s ++ if r then " exists" else " does not exist"
```

I would like to be able to check a list of files and then perform another function at the end depending on if all tests passed?

At the moment I can only think of doing the checks again separately with something like

```
allPassed = do 
            l <- mapM doesFileExist [`list of files`]
            if all (==True) l then "all ok" else "meh"
```

Comment: So you are looking for something like an `allM` function, a monadic equivalent of `all`?

Comment: My recommendation: don't bother. Just do the thing you want to do with the files and catch the exception if they don't exist. After all, they may cease to exist between performing this check and doing the next step, so you'll have to handle the exception anyway if you want a robust program!

Comment: We don't know the OP's application, but sometimes it can desirable to perform a "pre-flight check" before embarking on an expensive or time-consuming operation to ensure it isn' going to fail for an "obvious" reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `foldM` like this:

```
import Control.Monad

check :: FilePath -> IO Bool
check = undefined

process files = do
  allok <- foldM (\b f -> fmap (b &&) (check f)) True files
  if allok then putStrLn "All OK" else putStrLn "Oops"
```

Note this will always perform all of the tests.

The [docs for `allM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html#v:allM) says it is short-circuiting, so

```
do allok <- allM check files
   if allok then ... else ...
```

will stop performing the check after the first failure.

**Update**

Here is some demonstration code:

```
import Control.Monad

check :: Int -> IO Bool
check x =  do putStrLn ("x = " ++ show x)
              return $ even x

process files = do
  allok <- foldM (\b f -> fmap (b &&) (check f)) True files
  if allok then putStrLn "All OK" else putStrLn "Oops"

main = do process [1..5]   -- will print "Oops"
          process [2,4,6]  -- will print "All OK"
```

Comment: my `check` function returns a `IO Bool`, that is the problem that I have.. I actually want the `check` to print something to console for each file and then at the end I want to do a final output that is dependant on all files passing.

Comment: That actually works perfectly for what I need. Plus you prevented me struggling with `allM`. Great answer and thank you for your time! #note to self to reach for folds and scans more readily!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `allM` from `Control.Monad.Loops` package. It quits early if it sees that any of the value is false which is useful if your checking involves some expensive computations.

Here is a simple example:

```hs
import Control.Monad.Loops

doesFileExist :: FilePath -> IO Bool
doesFileExist path
    | path == "holiday.jpg" = return True
    | path == "me.jpg" = return True
    | path == "pop song.mp3" = return True
    | otherwise = return False

check :: FilePath -> IO Bool
check s = do
    r <- doesFileExist s

    putStrLn $ s ++ if r
                        then " exists"
                        else " does not exist"

    return r

main :: IO ()
main = do
    allPassed <- allM check ["holiday.jpg", "cat.mp4", "me.jpg"]

    if allPassed
        then putStrLn "Yes"
        else putStrLn "No"
```